# Triggering a workflow on the creation of a 1:N Relationship?

Tags: workflow, dynamics-crm, relationship, dynamics-crm-2011

I am trying to run a workflow on the creation of a 1:n relationship.

I have a Contact entity, and PortalRole entity. When I associate the PortalRole with the contact I would like to trigger a workflow which sends out welcome emails to the users.

The PortalRoles are assigned to the contacts from a ribbon button which launches a HTML web resource and uses JSON / JQuery and the REST services to create the associations.

How can I call the workflow? I need to grab the Contacts email address and send them 1 of 2 emails depending on how many associations they have (new portal user or portal user gaining extra roles)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This blog post provides a very good explanation of dealing with relationships.

> **(So Many) Many-to-Many Options: Which to Use?**
>
> So…of these three approaches, which is best? As always, it depends on
>   what you need to do, but here are some rules of thumb you can use as
>   guidance:
>
> **Native N:N**
>
> Probably the easiest to configure but the most limiting. Use when you
>   only need to know that two records are connected to each other but you
>   don’t need additional information about the connection itself.
>
> Examples:
>
> Custom entity Industry with an N:N to Account Add a custom N:N
>   relationship between the Competitor and Territory entities to track
>   which competitors are active in which territories Custom entity Color
>   with an N:N to Contact (you don’t track your contacts’ favorite
>   colors???)
>
> **Manual N:N**
>
> A little more work to configure, but generally worth the effort. Use
>   when in addition to knowing two records are connected, you also need
>   information about the connection, such as its status, when it was
>   created and so forth.
>
> Examples:
>
> Associations and Members  Events and Registrations (1:N from Contact
>   to Registration, 1:N from Event to Registration)  Subscribers and
>   Subscriptions (1:N from Contact to custom entity “Subscription”, 1:N
>   from custom entity “Subscription Product” to Subscription)
>
> **Connections and Connection Roles**
>
> As I mentioned above, these are actually a specific implementation of
>   the Manual approach. And if you delve into this a little, you’ll find
>   that the Connection entity is a bona-fide customizable entity. You can
>   even customize it, adding custom fields to the connection form and so
>   forth. But…be careful about overdoing it: there’s only one Connection
>   entity, and customizations made for one Connection Role generally will
>   not be applicable to another one.
>
> One specific advantage of these is that a single connection role can
>   connect records of different types (e.g., contacts can refer other
>   contacts, accounts and opportunities)
>
> This is a judgment call, but I’d say to use these when you need to
>   track some information about the actual connections (such as when
>   they’re created and how many there are…), but not that much. Examples:
>
> Referrals (Contact to Contact, Contact to Account, Contact to
>   Opportunity) Former Employee (Contact to Account, Lead to Account)
>   Board of Directors (Contact to custom entity “Board”, Lead to Board)

http://community.dynamics.com/product/crm/crmtechnical/b/richardknudson/archive/2011/05/08/many-to-many-relationships-in-dynamics-crm-2011.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You should build your workflow for the PortalRole entity and trigger it from Create. You'll still be able to access Contact fields in the workflow.

The trick is in your last requirement - send "Email A" for the first role association and then "Email B" for the each additional association.

You could add a Yes/No field to Contact called "First Role Assigned." Your workflow would look something like this:

- If Contact:FirstRoleAssigned = Yes

  - Send "Email B"
- Else

  - Send "Email A"
  - Set Contact:FirstRoleAssigned = Yes

Comment: But I dont want the workflow to be triggered on a new Role being created. It's when a person is assigned to that role if that makes sense? I'm now thinking I need to use Connections as I can then trigger the workflow from there?

Comment: If Contact has a 1:N relationship to PortalRole, then "assigning a role to a person" is really just creating of PortalRole with a ContactId Lookup set to the Contact. In your Web Resource, don't you use a Create request for PortalRole? If you are using "Associate" then it is a Many to Many relationship.

Comment: It show up as 2 relationships 1:n from contact and portalrole 1:n so it is a many-many relationship.